# Getting the value from the inline/embedded bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a problem by getting the selected value from the embedded/inline bootstrap datetimepicker.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 datepicker_area" style="background: red;">
                <div style="overflow:hidden;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div id="datetimepicker" data-date="12/03/2012 12:00 PM"></div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="date" id="my_hidden_input" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $("#datetimepicker").on("changeDate", function(event) {
                            $("input[type='hidden'][name='date']").val(
                                    $('#datetimepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
                            )
                        });

                        $(function () {
                            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                                inline: true,
                                sideBySide: true
                            });

                            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
                            $('#datetimepicker').on("changeDate", function() {
                                $('#my_hidden_input').val(
                                        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('getFormattedDate')
                                );
                            });


                        });
                    </script>
                </div>

            </div>
```

There is nothing happening with my hidden input.
He's not saving the value in it.

I've got the code from the bootstrap docu.

Somebody knows how it works?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Bootstrap 3 Datepicker, you need `dp.change` event.

Reference: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/

Replace your changeDate event `$('#datetimepicker').on("changeDate", function() {});` 
to 
`$('#datetimepicker').on('dp.change', function(event) {});`

You can than get the date using `event.date` or even better, format the date `event.date.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a')`

**Example:**
`$('#datetimepicker').on('dp.change', function(event) { alert(event.date); });`

**Please refer below solution:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true
  });
  $('#datetimepicker').on('dp.change', function(event) {
    //console.log(moment(event.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'));
    //console.log(event.date.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'));
    $('#selected-date').text(event.date);
    var formatted_date = event.date.format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a');
    $('#my_hidden_input').val(formatted_date);
    $('#hidden-val').text($('#my_hidden_input').val());
  });
});
```

```css
#selected-date,
#hidden-val {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<div>
  Selected Date: <span id="selected-date"></span>
  <br/>
  <br/>Value of hidden field: <span id="hidden-val"></span>
  <br/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 datepicker_area" style="background: red;">
  <div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="datetimepicker" data-date="12/03/2012 12:00 PM"></div>
          <input type="hidden" name="date" id="my_hidden_input" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you! It helped very well.
I didn't know that the event has changed. :)

Comment: @Florianb I'm glad it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 6):

Move your hidden input inside the div (container of the inline datetimepicker). And, datetimepicker will automatically use it. Tested on version 4.17.47.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <div id="datetimepicker" data-date="12/03/2012 12:00 PM">
       <input type="hidden" name="date" id="my_hidden_input" value="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beloow hidden input worked for me

```
<input type="hidden" name="date" id="my_hidden_input" value="">
```

Assigned the datetimepicker directly to hidden element via id

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#my_hidden_input').datetimepicker({
            inline: true, 
            sideBySide: true
        });
    });
</script>
```